# what are the steps to check before uploading a django project to github to secure the project

Tags: python, django, github

When I uploaded my project to GitHub it sends me an email saying that my secret key is exposed to the project.

**So what are the things to check before uploading a Django project to GitHub**

Comment: Take a look at https://owasp.org/www-community/controls/Static_Code_Analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code follows best practices for modern web-development, all sensitive information lives in codebase and `settings.py`. Things to look for – signing secrets and hashing salt/pepper.

I would say, as a rule of thumb – you should never have `settings.py` that you expect to use in production saved in version control system (at least, unencrypted).

If you're trying to push development state, please explicitly change your secrets in `settings.py` to something obviously non-secret (like `not-a-secret`). Django generates quite "strong" secrets by default. I'd guess github analyzer is unhappy with that. Note tho, that changing secrets will affect a lot of ares – i.e. sessions or old pw reset links will be invalid, etc.

---

As related topic – please take a look at [deployment checklist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/)